# how to filter the values of dictionaries of a list based on the certain value and arrange them in sorting order in python?

Tags: python, dictionary

I have a list of dictionaries, it has different combinations of keys and values.

```
list_ = [{'r':'640x360','b':500},{'r':'1280x720','b':3000}, {'r':'1920x1080','b':4000},{'r':'1920x1080','b':5000}, {'r':'1280x720','b':3100}, {'b':'1280x720','t':3300}]
```

I want this dictionary to be sorted first, and then based on the value of 'b' it has to be modified. Suppose for the resolution value 'r' is '1280x720' and it has different bitrates in 'b' in different dictionaries.

Let's take example of '1280x720' case.
for '1280x720' I want minimum bitrate would be 2000. If the value 'b' is lesser than the 2000, it has to take 2000 as 'b'.

If the 2 dictionaries same resolution and have +-300 difference in bitrate 'b' then it has to keep the dict with higher value and pop out the other.

And if the value 'b' is more than the minimum we have to keep that dictionary too.

Entries of '1280x720' in input

```
[{'r':'1280x720','b':3000},{'r':'1280x720','b':3100}, {'b':'1280x720','t':3300},{'r':'1280x720','b':1300}, {'r':'1280x720','b':2500}]
```

Entries of '1280x720' in the output I am expecting.

```
[{'r':'1280x720','b':2000},{'r':'1280x720','b':2500},{'r':'1280x720','b':3300}]
```

I have tried sorting them with below piece of code but unable to continue the rest.

```
new_rep = [dict(t) for t in set(tuple(d.items()) for d in list_)]
```

I got the list of sorted dicts.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: sorted based on what? Also, is this entry "{'b':'1280x720','t':2000}" correct in the list? Seems odd comparing against the other items.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This looks to work :

```
data = [{'r':'1280x720','b':3000},{'r':'1280x720','b':3100}, {'r':'1280x720','b':3300},{'r':'1280x720','b':1300}]
sorted_data = sorted(data, key=lambda d: -d['b'])

print(sorted_data)

result = []
for item in sorted_data:
    if item['b'] < 2000:
        item['b'] = 2000
    new_res = True
    for res_item in result:
        if (res_item['b'] > item['b']  and res_item['b'] - item['b'] <= 300) or (res_item['b'] < item['b']  and item['b']  - res_item['b'] <= 300):
            new_res = False
    if new_res:
        result.append(item)

result = sorted(result, key=lambda d: d['b'])
print(result)
```

output :

```
[{'r': '1280x720', 'b': 2000}, {'r': '1280x720', 'b': 2500}, {'r': '1280x720', 'b': 3300}]
```

Comment: almost near. Check for this input combination, [{'r': '1280x720', 'b': 2300}, {'r': '1280x720', 'b': 2500}, {'r': '1280x720', 'b': 3000}, {'r': '1280x720', 'b': 3100}, {'r': '1280x720', 'b': 3300}, {'r': '1280x720', 'b': 1300}], it is missing the 'b':2500 entry.

Comment: I edited the sort function it should works now ;)

Comment: result is not having the highest value 'b', it is supposed to have the highest 'b' value. I am expecting 3300, not 3000
[{'r': '1280x720', 'b': 2000}, {'r': '1280x720', 'b': 2500}, {'r': '1280x720', 'b': 3300}]

Comment: Edited ;) Just had to sort by desc